# Can't access updated state inside useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a node server which listens for the `load video` event and then emits `load` event, to load a video.

I listen for this event inside my client-side like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    socketRef.current = io.connect('/');

    socketRef.current.on("load", () => {
        loadVideo();
    })
}, []);
```

For this example, the `loadVideo` function just logs the value of `videoID`, which gets set like this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="video link" value={videoID} onChange={e => setVideoID(e.target.value)} />
```

Every time when the `loadVideo` function gets executed from inside the useEffect, it logs the initial state, which is an empty string, but if I were to call the function from some other function which is not inside a useEffect, then it logs the updated value. Could anyone explain why that is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your `useEffect` has no dependencies, meaning it's called on component mounting only. I would add the `videoId` as its dependency.

And just a sidenote, if you posted your `loadVideo` code here, it wouldn't hurt :)

Comment: ```
useEffect(() => {
    socketRef.current = io.connect('/');

    socketRef.current.on("load", () => {
        loadVideo();
    })
}, [videoId]);
```

something like this

Comment: yeah exactly that

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The `loadVideo` function just console.logs the `videoID` value. How would you write the code if I don't want the `useEffect` to run on every `videoID` change, because I would like to trigger the `load` event only on a button click?

Comment: Then you would forget about the `useEffect` and just assign your `loadVideo` to an `onClick` event like this: `<button onClick={loadVideo}>load video</button>'.

Comment: I was thinking about this approach, but I think I need to put `socketRef.current.on("load", () => { loadVideo(); })` inside useEffect, because I don't want to set more then one `load` event listener, and the `socket` listener itself is used, because it will run `loadVideo` for all users.